# If column contain particular string then result is NULL else another column, how to apply this Expression Transformation in informatica?

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I Have tried the following function and code, but I could not return the column value.

Column Names:
`CPOP_SCORE_NB,FILLER_COL_00010`

```
DECODE( TRUE
      ,  FILLER_COL_00010=  '?', ' '
      , FILLER_COL_00010 = ' ', CPOP_SCORE_NB
                        , 'NA' )

IIF(FILLER_COL_00010 = '?', ' ' ,CPOP_SCORE_NB)
```

Now i want to return the `CPOP_SCORE_NB` column value if `FILLER_COL_00010` column value not having `?`.

I am new to informatica, Anyone can help me resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 1):

> i want to return the CPOP_SCORE_NB column value if FILLER_COL_00010 column value not having '?'.

In SQL, you would write:

```
(case when FILLER_COL_00010 not like '%?%' then CPOP_SCORE_NB end)
```

Comment: Exactly,but how to apply the same in informatica and return the column name for else condition

Comment: Unfortunately, informatica doesn't have 'like' so you can use `INSTR`.

Comment: I just want to note that the question is tagged SQL and `LIKE` is supported in every database that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use REG_MATCH Function in your case,

```html
IIF(REG_MATCH(FILLER_COL_00010,'.*?*.')=FALSE,CPOP_SCORE_NB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simple solution for your statement - `i want to return the CPOP_SCORE_NB column value if FILLER_COL_00010 column value not having ?`

```
IIF(INSTR(FILLER_COL_00010,'?')=0, CPOP_SCORE_NB)
```

`INSTR` will return location of `?` in FILLER_COL_00010.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, i tried all the options. But below worked for me:

IIF(FILLER_COL_00010 = '?',NULL,CPOP_SCORE_NB)